Elif condition that is intended to break the function when it reaches a certain value doesn't work
i have been working on a program that detects the number of times "enter" has been pressed, the problem is that the elif/if condition that is supposed to break the function when the variable reaches a certain value, keeps counting the number of times "enter" has been pressed instead of breaking the function.
from pynput import keyboard

keystroke = 0

def on_release(key):
    print(key)
    global keystroke
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        keystroke += 1 #this sums to the variable keystroke +1.
        print(keystroke)
    elif keystroke > 3: #This intends to break the fuction when keystroke reaches or surpasses 3.
        return False

with keyboard.Listener( #Calling the function here.
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()



......
this is the output.
Output 

key.enter
1
key.enter
2
key.enter
3
key.enter
4
....


elif should be if, because if it entes the first if, it won't check your elif condition (remember: elif = else if).

Because of the elif statement, your current program checks the number of keystrokes only if a key other than Enter has been pressed. Instead, you should replace the elif with a separate if statement so the condition is checked even when you press Enter.
Also, if you want the function to break when keystroke reaches 3, replace ">" with ">=":
from pynput import keyboard

keystroke = 0

def on_release(key):
    print(key)
    global keystroke
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        keystroke += 1 #this sums to the variable keystroke +1.
        print(keystroke)
    if keystroke >= 3: #This intends to break the fuction when keystroke reaches or surpasses 3.
        return False

with keyboard.Listener( #Calling the function here.
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()


from pynput import keyboard

# working on a program that detects the number of times "enter" has been pressed, and then prints that number

keystroke = 0
def on_release(key):
    global keystroke
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        keystroke = keystroke + 1
        print(keystroke)
        if keystroke > 2:
            return False
    return True

with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

Two indented if statements are used because Python starts counting from 0.
